# ASP.Net - Mvc5 : LINQ , Saving duplicate record problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I am coding daily counter. Database Counter Table is empty. If someone is my first visitor of current day, then I am adding a record to database and i am setting counter=1; After this, when other visitor visit current day, then i am increasing my counter++ and i am updating the record.

So I my records must be like this:

Date:2018-10-**01** counter:23

Date:2018-10-**02** counter:65

Date:2018-10-**03** counter:20

Date:2018-10-**04** counter:89

My problem is this: If the site get visitor same time, linq save 2 record for same day. Like this:

Date:2018-10-**01** counter:23

**Date:2018-10-02 counter:1  //First record: counter=1**

**Date:2018-10-02 counter:65 //Second record: counter=65**

Date:2018-10-**03** counter:20

Date:2018-10-**04** counter:1  //First record

Date:2018-10-**04** counter:89 //second record

Date must be unique. How can I resolve this problem? My code is below. Thanks a lot.

```
public static int IncreaseCounter_DailySiteVisitors()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        using (var context = new MyProjectEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
                var obj = (from record in context.CounterDailySiteVisitor
                           where 
                           record.DateRecord != null 
                           && record.DateRecord.HasValue 
                           && record.DateRecord.Value.Year == Today.Year 
                           && record.DateRecord.Value.Month == Today.Month
                           && record.DateRecord.Value.Day == Today.Day
                           select record).FirstOrDefault();



               //var obj = context.CounterDailyVisitor.Where(x => x.DateRecord != null && ((DateTime)x.DateRecord).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") == DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")).FirstOrDefault();
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    counter = obj.Count ?? 0;
                    counter++;
                    obj.Count = counter;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    var newRecordObj = context.CounterDailySiteVisitor.Create();
                    newRecordObj.Count = 1;
                    newRecordObj.DateRecord = Today;
                    context.CounterDailySiteVisitor.Add(newRecordObj);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }


        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: if this is concurrency problem  which I'm not 100% convinced it is, but if it is then add a lock... around this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the chances of this being hit by two thread at the same time is quite low.
but i guess technically it can so you would need to wrap this in a lock

Something like below...

```
public static int IncreaseCounter_DailySiteVisitors()
{
    private readonly object somethingObject = new object();

    var context = new MyProjectEntities() 

    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var todaysRecord = context.CounterDailyVisitor
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.DateRecord.Year == Today.Year
                            && x.DateRecord.Month == Today.Month
                           && x.DateRecord.Day == Today.Day
                );
    if (todaysRecord != null)
    {
       //the existing count + 1
       todaysRecord.Count = todaysRecord.Count++;
    }
    else
    {

       Lock(somethingObject)
       {
           //recheck
           var todaysRecord = context.CounterDailyVisitor
                   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.DateRecord.Year == Today.Year
                       && x.DateRecord.Month == Today.Month
                    && x.DateRecord.Day == Today.Day
                );

           if (todaysRecord != null)
           {
               //the existing count + 1
               todaysRecord.Count = todaysRecord.Count++;
           }
           else
           {
            var newRecordObj = new CounterDailyVisitor();
            newRecordObj.Count = 1;
            newRecordObj.DateRecord =  DateTime.Now; //this shouldnt be nullable

            context.CounterDailySiteVisitor.Add(newRecordObj);
           }    
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common concurrency problem i.e. race condition. You will either have to `Lock` around the code that reads and subsequently updates/inserts the value. Or you should call a stored procedure and have all the logic inside the stored proc.

`Lock` comes with it's own set of issues if you're planning on using a web farm or running multiple instances of this MVC app.